# Simple ruby TCP request doesn't hit the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, tcp, websocket

I have a simple ruby script to upload file to the server/web app through TCP connection but it doesn't work.When i run the script nothing happens on the web app/server side.The server works fine as i have tried to upload file with CURL and it did upload.Take a look at my code below and let me know what am i doing wrong.I am using ruby 1.9.2-p290.Thank you in advance.

```
require 'socket'   

host = "myapp.herokuapp.com"
port = 80

client = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

client.print("POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1\r\n")
client.print("Host: myapp.herokuapp.com\r\n")
client.print ("Accept: */* \r\n")
client.print ("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=AaB03x \r\n")


client.print("\n" + "AaB03x"+ "\n" "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='cam.jpg' \n Content-Type: image/jpeg \r\n")
client.print ("\r\n")
data = File.open("./pic.jpg", "rb") {|io| io.read}
client.print (data)
client.print ("\r\n") 
client.print("boundary=AaB03x\r\n")

client.close
```

IRB console

```
>require 'socket'
 => true 
>  client = TCPSocket.open("myapp.herokuapp.com", 80)
 => #<TCPSocket:fd 3>
> client.print("GET /api/users HTTP/1.1")
  => nil 
> client.print("POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1")
  => nil
```

Comment: Please notice: `print` uses `write` internally, but doesn't check the result - this means that **there is no guarantee all the data will be sent**. Each more on socket programming and consider using `write` and `select` to emulate a blocking write that will block until all the data was sent, or use an evented/threaded solution to continue writing any data that wasn't written the first time.

Comment: How is this websocket related? (I will remind you that websocket is the name of a communication protocol, it isn't a name for tcp/ip sockets) ... please remove the `websocket` tag if it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are sending a valid HTTP request.

1. You need a `Content-Length` header. This means you need to assemble the body in advance so you can determine its length for the header, then send the body. If you get this wrong the server could end up blocking trying to read more input that doesn’t come.
2. Your multipart boundaries need fixing. They should start with `--`, then the token from the header: `--AaB03x`. The final one should end with `--` too: `--AaB03x--`. Make sure there’s no trailing whitespace in the header as well, that can cause issues.

Some other things that probably won’t prevent the request being parsed but you should tidy up:

1. Newlines in the headers should be `\r\n` not just `\n`.
2. Header lines shouldn’t have any whitespace before them.

```
require 'socket'   

host = "myapp.herokuapp.com"
port = 80

client = TCPSocket.open(host, port)

# Write out the headers.
client.print("POST /api/binary HTTP/1.1\r\n")
client.print("Host: myapp.herokuapp.com\r\n")
client.print ("Accept: */* \r\n")
# Note: no trailing whitespace.
client.print ("Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=AaB03x\r\n")

# Assemble the body.
# Note \r\n for all line endings, body doesn't start with newline.
# Boundary marker starts with '--'.
body = "--AaB03x\r\n"
body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='datafile'; filename='cam.jpg'\r\n"
# Header starts at left of line, no leading whitespace.
body << "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
body << "\r\n"
data = File.open("./pic.jpg", "rb") {|io| io.read}
body << data
body << "\r\n"
# Final boundary marker has trailing '--'
body << "--AaB03x--\r\n"

# Now we can write the Content-Length header, since
# we now know the size of the body.
client.print "Content-Length: #{body.bytesize}\r\n"
# Blank line.
client.print "\r\n"
# Finally write out the body.
client.print body

# In reality you would want to parse the response from
# the server before closing the socket.
client.close
```

Comment: Consider minimizing the `print` calls, to unify write operations and maximize the use of the system's `write` buffer... also `print` uses `write` internally, (`rb_io_write` calls `write`), but doesn't check the result - this means that **some of the data might not get written due to system socket buffer limits**. Use `write` and `select` to emulate a blocking write that will block until all the data was sent, or use an evented/threaded solution to continue writing any data that wasn't written the first time.